# deprication of tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib) I can see that tf.contrib has been deprecated for tensorflow 2.
However, the [Migration Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/migration_guide) page isn't found.

I'm essentially trying to do write an rnn in tensorflow 2.1.
Are there any similar keras libraries? or will I have to downgrade to tensorflow 1 (even though tensorflow is really telling us to start adopting v2.x)

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to use the `tensoflow_addons` and follow the installation of github.

After that you need use LayerNormLSTMCell (is equal to LayerNormBasicLSTMCell).

More info here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/rnn

https://github.com/tensorflow/addons

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/rnn/LayerNormLSTMCell